# HTML inside material ui Accordion

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, accordion

I'm trying to render HTML content inside an Accordion.

```
import {Accordion, AccordionDetails, AccordionSummary, Typography} from '@material-ui/core';
import { Badge } from 'reactstrap';

...

const buildAccordion = (f, i) => {
    return (
        <Accordion expanded={expanded === `panel${i}`} onChange={handleChange(`panel${i}`)}>
            <AccordionSummary aria-controls={`panel${i}d-content`} id={`panel${i}d-header`}>
            <Typography>{f.Question}</Typography>
            </AccordionSummary>
            <AccordionDetails>
            <Typography>
                <Badge color="primary">Answer</Badge>
                <p>
                    {f.Answer}
                </p>
            </Typography>
            </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
    );
}
```

However, when I render, my `f.Answer` shows:
`Steps to log in and create your account: <br><br> 1. Go to <a href="https://mysite/" target="_blank">https://mysite/</a> to access the login page <br>`

Why are the html tags showing as strings?

Comment: You should share the value of `f`, in order to decide which is causing the problem

Comment: I shared it. f.Answer is `Steps to log in and create your account: <br><br> 1. Go to <a href="https://mysite/" target="_blank">https://mysite/</a> to access the login page <br>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**f.title** is a string containing HTML elements if you want to render it as a real HTML element just

**change :**

```
<p>
   {f.Answer}
</p>
```

**to :**

```
  <p  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: f.Answer}} />
```